# Loading Parent Context value when child data is NULL in mustache , javascripting , JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json, mustache

I am trying to display JSON data through mustache. When the specified attribute is `NULL`, the mustache is display parent value when child is `NULL`.

In below example i am trying to print the values. When the color attribute is `NULL`. I want to handle the null value and print my own value, but is display as "Parent Color" as shown below.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gdFrk/302/)
`enter code here`

Comment: <ul>
    {{#slides}}
    <li>
        Title: {{title}} <br/>  
        Color: {{color}} <br/>          
    </li>
    {{/slides}}
</ul>

---------

var data = {
  author: "Jones",
  slides: [
    { title: "Hat", color: null },
    { title: "Cat", color: "red" }
  ],
  title: "Parent Title", color: "Parent Color"
}

var template = document.body.innerHTML;
document.body.innerHTML = Mustache.render(template, data);

Comment: <ul>
    {{#slides}}
    <li>
        Title: {{title}} <br/>  
        Color: {{color}} <br/>          
    </li>
    {{/slides}}
</ul>